# How to write compressed data to Kafka in Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Is it possible to write gzip compressed data to Kafka from Spark streaming? Are there any examples/samples that shows how to write and read compressed data from Kafka in Spark streaming job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Just set the `compression.type` to `gzip`.

See [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/KafkaWordCount.scala) for complete example.

```
// Zookeeper connection properties
val props = new HashMap[String, Object]()
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokers)
props.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "gzip")
// add other props as needed

val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CLI or set in your server.properties file.

--compression-codec [compression-codec] The compression codec: either 'none',                                          'gzip', 'snappy', or 'lz4'.If specified without value, then it defaults to 'gzip'.
0 is the default value.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compression